# How to concat on axis 1 and fill all rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This is my current code that works but is slow:

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values = ["val1","val2"], index=['date'], columns = 'category2')
df = pd.merge(df,pivot_df,on="date",how="left",suffixes=["","_pivot")
```

But in my dataframe, there is only 1 unique date. So I can simply do this to speed up merge:

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values = ["val1","val2"], index=['date'], columns = 'category2').reset_index(drop=True)
pivot_df.columns = [str(col)+"_pivot" for col in pivot_df.columns.tolist()]
df = pd.concat([df,company_pivot],axis=1)
```

But since `pivot_df` shape is 1x226 and `df` shape is `550x2700`. The concat method just fill the first row of `df`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one dirty solution, but is there any better way?

```
pivot_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values = ["val1","val2"], index=['date'], columns = 'category2').reset_index(drop=True)
pivot_df.columns = [str(col)+"_pivot" for col in pivot_df.columns.tolist()]

pivot_df = pd.concat([pivot_df]*10,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
pivot_df = pd.concat([pivot_df]*55,axis=0,ignore_index=True)

df = pd.concat([df,company_pivot],axis=1)
```

Just creating duplicate rows in 2 lines, since 1 line seems slower.

Also, If I even add more rows dynamically, this becomes a more mess.